# Manually uploading a file with VichUploaderBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using ***Symfony 2.8***, and i used ***VichUploaderBundle*** to upload files.
the problem is when i want to upload (insert, update) files manually it doesn't work. i've searched everywhere i found nothing, The documentation says this :

> If manually uploading a file (i.e. not using Symfony Form) ensure an
>   instance of 'UploadedFile' is injected into this setter to trigger the
>   update. If this bundle's configuration parameter 'inject_on_load' is
>   set to 'true' this setter must be able to accept an instance of 'File'
>   as the bundle will inject one here during Doctrine hydration.

I do not how to do this manually, **and i have to do this manually**; please i need help with that !

here is my update controller :

```
$qb = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
            $qb->update('LocationBundle:Vehicule v')
                    ->set('v.accessoires', '?1')
                    ->set('v.imageFile', '?2')
                    ->where('v.id = ?3')

                    ->setParameter('1', $editForm->get('accessoires')->getData())
                    ->setParameter('2', $editForm->get('imageFile')->getData())
                    ->setParameter('3', $request->get('id'))
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the way you're updating the data isn't correct, you must update the entity. This is the first step you need to learn after that you have to get the entity you want to update or create one, you will need to set the method with the file in params of the method. See [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) for entity and doctrine in symfony2.